# Hilbert's Hotel. Primes powers method. What is wrong here?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Specifically, I am concerned with proving that an infinite number of coaches each with an infinite number of guests can be accommodated in an infinite hotel. I understand methods for proving this such as using the same technique to proving the rationals are countable.

But I am having difficulty understanding how using a method involving prime powers for a pairing function of naturals to naturals is reasonable. So in this prime powers method each natural number is mapped to $p^n$ where p is any prime. This is done for all primes.

I understand that if you had a sequence: $2^n$, the number of terms in this sequence would be countable. But I do not see how the set of natural numbers can support the size of $2^n$.

This is since the number $2^n$ is uncountable as n goes to infinity. So the set of naturals cannot contain these numbers. And so the infinite hotel cannot have such large room numbers. (I have taken this from the fact that the power set of the naturals is uncountable.)

But I am also very convinced by the idea that for each finite natural the function $2^n$ does map to a finite number.

So where does the above reasoning go wrong?

Comment: You might be getting confused between $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $2^n$. $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is a set with uncountable cardinality, but $2^n$ is a perfectly valid injective function from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself.

Comment: First create a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{P}$. And then let $g:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ be given by $g(n,k)=f(n)^k$.

Comment: In general, it is impossible to accommodate an infinite number of coaches each with an infinite number of guests in Hilbert's hotel. The number of coaches and number of guests per coach must not exceed *countable* infinity.

Comment: So the fact that $2^N$ is uncountable doesn't determine if all $2^n$ for all naturals n will be contained by the naturals.

Answer (score 2):

Just because $2^{\aleph_0}$ is uncountable does not mean that $2^n$ somehow tends to something uncountable as $n\to\omega$. In fact, $\sup\{2^n:n\in\omega\}=\omega,$ i.e. regular old countable infinity, not the continuum. Just like your intuition suggests based on $2^n$ being finite for any finite $n$. The continuum function (the function that takes a cardinal to the cardinality of its power set) is discontinuous in this sense. Another way of looking at it is that while the cardinality of the set of all sets of natural numbers is uncountable, the cardinality of the set of all finite sets of natural numbers is countable.

Comment: I find this odd: $sup\{2^n:n∈ω\}=ω$. My thinking is that $2^ℵ$ should be the upper bound. I need to look read further about transfinite numbers etc. Since I know what I just wrote doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You're thinking that because you're used to exponentiation being a continuous function.  But as @spaceisdarkgreen points out, when applied to cardinal exponentiation, it's not.

Comment: @AppmRllo What all this is showing is that one's intuition that exponentiation should commute with limits in cardinal arithmetic is in fact contradicted by the more basic axioms of how sets (finite or infinite) work (and this isn't the first time this has happened - the original version of Hilbert's Hotel indicated that not every pattern occurring for finite sets holds for infinite sets). There's a very important bit of mathematical psychology going on here: what do we use to distinguish between arguments for/against basic axioms on the one hand and vague intuitions on the other? *(continued)*

Comment: However, that's not an easily-treated issue, and one should have significant experience with set theory before attacking it. For now I recommend doing the following. First, convince yourself that the usual basic axioms of set theory do in fact prove that cardinal exponentiation is discontinuous in the sense above. Second, try to write down an argument supporting your intuition to the contrary: why do you think it *should* be continuous? Note that if you buy the original form of Hilbert's Hotel you can't lean on an analogy with finite sets, since you already know those break down. *(continued)*

Comment: The slipperiness you encounter there, in contrast with the complete explicitness in the proof in the first task, will help you develop the right intuition.